# Python: "zsh: segmentation fault" error causes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just playing around with a python library called 'Pyautogui.' Everything was going fun and cool until upon one run, I hit a `zsh: segmentation fault`. Pyautogui has stopped working on my local machine since. Any code using the Pyautogui library crashes with the same error.

Not a big practical issue as I was just experimenting personally, but I am curious as to the cause of the issue as to why code that ran fine a few times, all of a sudden pops what seems to be a memory related error and then crashes an entire library!

Code I ran about 5 times before it crashed is beyond simple, and no issues with Pip or anything. If any experts on Python compilation and/or C have any ideas, would greatly appreciate your input!

```
import pyautogui as auto
from time import sleep


def move_da_mouse():
    while True:
        # this just moves the mouse 100px, 200px on the x and y axis of the screen respectively
        auto.moveTo(100, 200)
        sleep(30)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    move_da_mouse()
```

Comment: Voting to close because this is not an issue with your code, it's a [known issue in the library](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/639).

Comment: @ZacAnger This is no cause to close. It is an issue with the development environment and the information that there is a version incompatibility is valuable.

Comment: @KlausD. My apologies, I've seen other folks with more reputation and time on the site vote to close when the issue is a bug upstream, so thought that was the way to go. I retracted my vote (and I'll read the manual when I'm not sure in the future).

Comment: @ZacAnger Thank you for the issue flag. Created a pyenv for Python 3.5.x and it worked, anything higher and it seems to crash. Will close the q. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the python library you are using, 'Pyautogui', is attempting to access a memory beyond its reach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).